# UITabBar not selected during app startup

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to replicate the look of my app during start-up with how iTunes and App Store appear.

Specifically my app has a tab bar that will get populated when it has finished downloading info from a web site - until then it should look empty.  The only way I can appear to do this so far is to have an empty name and image for the UITabBarItem.  It's only minor, but this item is 'selected' and is therefore a "lighter" color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by showing an image that I created by taking a screenshot of the App Store app then showing this during app loading.  When ready to populate the UITabBar simply add the bar items they are shown immediately.